# Facebook feed dialog iframe inside Facebook app

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps

I am trying to get an feed dialog iframe inside my Facebook app. But somehow it doesn't let me. The Iframe now looks like this:

[image: Facebook Iframe error]

I am trying this with the following code:

```
$html .= '<iframe style="width:800px; height:800px;" src="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id='.$appID.'&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/'.$appName.'&acces_token='.$accesToken.'"></iframe>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Hope someone knows what i am doing wrong... I just want to have the following inside the iframe:

[image: How i must show.]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set `display=iframe`. Your adjusted sample code would be (addition in **bold**):

```
$html .= '<iframe style="width:800px; height:800px;" src="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?display=iframe&app_id='.$appID.'&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/'.$appName.'&acces_token='.$accesToken.'"></iframe>'.PHP_EOL;
```

For more info, see 'Common Dialog Parameters' at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/